# How to spread two widgets in the same row to the extremes of the window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my window:

[image]

I want to place the values from the labels as far as possible in the window. I want to place them in the left and right extremes of the row.

Here is what I am doing that is not working:

```py
# output frame
self.out_frame = tk.Frame(self)
self.out_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew", pady=24)

# ... 

# take the hexadecimal value for example ->
ttk.Label(self.out_frame, text="Hexadecimal", font=sub_title_font).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
self.hex_out.set(str(hexnum))
ttk.Label(self.out_frame, textvariable=self.hex_out, font=sub_title_font).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
ttk.Separator(self.out_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew", pady=5)
```

To sum up, I am just sticking the value label and the actual value to West and East respectively for each row. However, I cannot get the parent frame (i.e., `out_frame`) to span the entire column space of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- add `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to expand `self.out_frame` to fill the available space horizontally
- add `self.out_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` to expand the column containing the number to fill the available space horizontally

Updated code:

```py
# allocate all the available space horizontally to column 0 inside parent
self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# output frame
self.out_frame = tk.Frame(self)
self.out_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew", pady=24)

# allocate all the available space horizontally to column 1 inside self.out_frame
self.out_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

# ...

# take the hexadecimal value for example ->
ttk.Label(self.out_frame, text="Hexadecimal", font=sub_title_font).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
self.hex_out.set(str(hexnum))
ttk.Label(self.out_frame, textvariable=self.hex_out, font=sub_title_font).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
ttk.Separator(self.out_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew", pady=5)
```

And the result:

[image]